# sfdx force:auth:web:login - reuse session on cron (MacOS)?

Tags: cron, salesforce, sfdx, salesforce-sfdx

Here is a simple script that detect if I am authenticated

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(sfdx auth:list | grep -c "my_org.my.salesforce.com") -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "sfdx not authenticated, please run : sfdx force:auth:web:login -s -a orgname"
    # echo "DEBUG : config:list [$(sfdx config:list)]" #same output as interactive mode
    # echo "DEBUG : auth:list [$(sfdx auth:list)]" #no value returned via cron
    exit 5
fi
```

sfdx is authenticated for my user in `"$HOME"/.sfdc/my@login.com.json` so my script proceed when run manually

When I run the bash file via cron (`crontab -e` with `03 * * * * /path/my_script.sh`), the `auth:list` has no entry even though `sfdx config:list` does have the configured entry

I tried to source my `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` files to no avail.

Is there a way to specify to use the same credential file used in my interactive terminal for `sfdx` ran from sfdx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following commands:

```
$ sfdx force:org:display -u <OrgUsername> --verbose --json >
authFile.json 

$ sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store -f authFile.json
```

The first command generates a forceurl in the JSON file and the second command uses the file generated by the first to login.

Comment: This did not work but nonetheless solves the discussion as cron with sdfx is impossible on mac
-> 
ERROR running auth:sfdxurl:store:  Command failed with response:
 - security: SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent (<default>): Write permissions error.
Try this:
Determine why this command failed to set an encryption key for user julien: [/usr/bin/security add-generic-password -a local -s sfdx -w abcdefg].
 --- 
I'll try [launchd](https://superuser.com/questions/1050993/cant-use-usr-bin-security-to-retrieve-password-from-keychain-via-cron)

Comment: Just to confirm that launchd worked (adding Full Disk Access to `/bin/bash` and launching the script from launchd user job as parameter of `/bin/bash` - the authentication saved by interactive user is used without issue in this case...
And as expected; cron still does not authenticate sfdx even to run via FDA `/bin/bash` on Mac Monterrey

Comment: So sfdx can't run via cron and must run using launchd and plist files?